# Spring Boot application build failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, build

I am trying to build locally this repository https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic
I followed the steps from the repo but the build result looks like this:

`[INFO] BUILD FAILURE`

`[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------`

`[INFO] Total time:  6.757 s`

`[INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-23T15:27:08+02:00`

`[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------`

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.1:build-info (default) on project spring-petclinic: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.1:build-info failed: Unable to load the mojo 'build-info' in the plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.1' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/springframework/boot/maven/BuildInfoMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0.`

My Java version is:

`$ java -version`

`openjdk version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18`

`OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.17+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04)`

`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.17+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04, mixed mode)`

And Maven version is:

`$ mvn -v`

`Apache Maven 3.6.0`

`Maven home: /usr/share/maven`

`Java version: 11.0.17, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`

`Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8`

`OS name: "linux", version: "5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-wsl2", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"`

I tried to run the steps from the repo, but that didn't worked for me.

Comment: The code was compiled with a newer Version of the jdk as it has at runtime

Comment: Spring Boot 3.X requires JDK17+ simply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Java 14 or above to handle this:

Java SE 14 (or JDK 14) is the version that handles class files with a version number of 61.0

Comment: Yeah.. In the pom.xml file the java version is set to 17 <java.version>17</java.version>..I updated the Java to Java 17, and the build was successful. It's strange because the repo said "it should work just as well with Java 11 or newer"..Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

class file version 61.0 = Java 17. If you are trying to run the project via your IDE, it will be using an independant java version from what's configured for your terminal's classpath.
The tutorial mentiones Intellij, so I'll assume that's what you're using. Go into `File -> Project Structure` and you will have your SDK and Language Level in there for that project, make sure they're the correct versions.